# How to delete git commits and merges to desired point in history

Tags: gitkraken

I'm using GitKraken. The current history for my repo looks like this:

[image: Current repo history]

However, I want to remove the most recent commit and merge,

[image]

so that my history looks like this:

[image]

I want to do this through GitKraken alone, without using the command line.

I have already tried `reset <branch> to this commit - hard`, with the `Master` branch checked out and with the `Authentication` branch checked out, but the history does not change at all.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's what I didn't understand: *the icons*.
The `8` icon (my Github profile logo) shows the status of that branch on Github. The computer symbol shows the status of that branch on my machine. In my case, they were out of sync. Even though I reset my local copy by performing `reset <branch> to this commit - hard`, GitKraken was still showing the later commit located on Github.

The solution: Overwrite the `master` branch on Github by right-clicking on the latest true commit and selecting `push`. It will give a warning, but that's okay.